# Server alias with WWW not working in firefox

Tags: apache-2.4

I have webserver configuration:

```
######
##  HTTP site.si
######

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site.si
ServerAlias www.site.si
Redirect / https://site.si/


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site.si [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.site.si
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} 
[END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>



######
##  HTTPS site.si
######

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName site.si
ServerAlias www.site.si
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site.si
SSLEngine on
..
```

And when i open page in chrome with [www.site.si](http://www.site.si) it is working fine, i get https://site.si but it doesnt work OK in firefox, i get certificate problem.

Any ideas ?

BR RK

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a certificate from a known issuer? If so,
It could be also be that the certificate itself is not created correctly and you're missing a CA in the chain, and firefox might pick it up.

You can also try to import the CA into the firefox certificates or try to find if there's an issue with your certificate (you can use a tool called XCA which can help you with this).

Importing certificate into firefox
https://www.jscape.com/blog/firefox-client-certificate

Comment: CA is from letsencrypt, so it should be good.